# numpy: limiting min value of a scalar, 1D or nD array

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Given a scalar, a 1D or an N-D numpy (numeric) array, I'd like to replace all values less than `threshold` with `threshold`.  So, for example:

```
def fn(a, threshold):
  return ???

fn(2, 2.5) => 2.5                                                             # scalar
fn([1, 2, 3, 4], 2.5) => [2.5, 2.5, 3, 4]]                                    # 1-D
fn[[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6]], 2.5) => [[2.5, 2.5, 3, 4], [2.5, 2.5, 4, 6]]  # 2-D
```

*(Note: For ease of reading, I've shown the arrays above with ordinary Python array syntax, but they're actually numpy.ndarrays.)*

I could use `if` statements and dispatch on the type of `a` to handle each case.  But I'm still wrapping my head around numpy's broadcast methods: is there a simple numpy idiom for handling this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
np.maximum([[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6]], 2.5)
```

Or [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
np.clip([[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6]], 2.5, np.inf)
```

Output:

```
array([[2.5, 2.5, 3. , 4. ],
       [2.5, 2.5, 4. , 6. ]])
```

Comment: Ah!  Yes.  I was trying to use `np.max()` rather than `np.maximum()` -- np.maximum() makes all the difference, and even works with a scalar.  And now all my unit tests work again!